# How can I convert a DOM element to a jQuery element?

Tags: jquery

I am creating an element with document.createElement().
Now how can I pass it to a function that only takes a Jquery object?

```
$("#id")
```

I can not use it, as the element has not been rendered in the page yet.

Comment: This quesion should be awarded as the best question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 518, accepted):

```
var elm = document.createElement("div");
var jelm = $(elm);//convert to jQuery Element
var htmlElm = jelm[0];//convert to HTML Element
```

Comment: This works because jquery will take not only a string selector, but an existing jquery object, or any valid dom object as an argument to the main $() query function.

Comment: What about the reverse? You have a jquery element and want to convert it to a dom element?

Comment: The reverse can be done by: http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/04/convert-jquery-object-to-dom-object.html

Comment: Hey @Marius will this work if elm contains a collection of DOM nodes?

Comment: I'm getting this error... https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/365615598342b220dc5735235682f0e3

Comment: @daremkd [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776584/js-selector-combined-with-jquery#47776584)

Answer (score 17):

What about constructing the element using jQuery? e.g.

```
$("<div></div>")
```

creates a new div element, ready to be added to the page. Can be shortened further to

```
$("<div>")
```

then you can chain on commands that you need, set up event handlers and append it to the DOM. For example

```
$('<div id="myid">Div Content</div>')
    .bind('click', function(e) { /* event handler here */ })
    .appendTo('#myOtherDiv');
```

Comment: actually i am getting the element from somewhere where i cant change the code

Answer (score 3):

So far best solution that I've made:

```
function convertHtmlToJQueryObject(html){
    var htmlDOMObject = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    return $(htmlDOMObject.documentElement);
}
```