# Create map legend to match OpenLayers.Style

Tags: openlayers, legend

I've created an OpenLayers.Style that colours my polygons, a style that sizes my points and all that jazz, now I want to explain to the user what those styles represent.

I can't see anything in OpenLayers that allows me to draw my own legend using those styles. Everything seems to point me towards the assumed map server that is sending me data, which I don't have.

At the moment it looks like I'll have to draw some sample points/areas and screen grab them to make my own legend. Is there a better way to do it based straight off the Style so I don't have to regenerate the images when the Style gets changed?

**Update**
I've had a good answer that relies on GeoExt (and thus ExtJS), I'd still like to hear if anyone has a jQuery compatible answer. Especially if it is plain Javascript and OpenLayers.

Comment: Have you looked at *GeoExt*? They provide a `LegendPanel` which I think does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my legend needs using the ol.Map-class as a container for the symbols. Maybe a bit of a hack, but seems to work for most (?) vector layers (I have no WMS's).

So what I'm doing is:

1. loop through the map layers and pick out the vector type with

   `if(lyr instanceof ol.layer.Vector)`
2. check what type of style is used and store in an array

   ```
   var style = lyr.getStyle();
   var image = style.getImage();
   if(image){
       if(image instanceof ol.style.Icon){
           //raster icon from url
           var icon2 = new ol.style.Icon( ({
               src: image.getSrc()
           }))
           var iconStyle2 = new ol.style.Style({
               image: icon2
           });
           row = {};
           row.style = iconStyle2;
           row.title = lyr.get('title');               
       }
       else{ //ol.style.RegularShape?
           row = {};
           row.style = style;
           row.title = lyr.get('title');               
       }
   }else{
       row = {};
       row.style = style;
       row.title = lyr.get('title');
   }
   ```
3. also store the geometry type

   ```
   //geometry type
   var feats = lyr.getSource().getFeatures();
   if (feats && feats.length>0){
       if(feats[0].getGeometry() instanceof ol.geom.Point || feats[0].getGeometry() instanceof ol.geom.MultiPoint){
           row.geomType="point";
       }else if (feats[0].getGeometry() instanceof ol.geom.LineString || feats[0].getGeometry() instanceof ol.geom.MultiLineString){
           row.geomType="line";
       }else{
           row.geomType="polygon";
       }
   }
   ```
4. loop through the stored to-be legend rows and construct the HTML elements needed, typically a div for the "mini-map" and the layer name

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < legendRows.length; i++) { 
       row = document.createElement("tr");
       //symbol
       cell = document.createElement("td");
       cell.style="width:35px";
       var div = document.createElement("div");
       div.style="width:32px; height:32px;";
       div.id = "mapLegendRowSymbolDiv" + i; 
       tble.appendChild(row);
       row.appendChild(cell);
       cell.appendChild(div);
       //layer title
       cell = document.createElement("td");      
       tble.appendChild(row);
       row.appendChild(cell);
       cell.innerHTML=legendRows[i].title; 
   }

   //append table
   $( "#legendText" ).empty();
   $( "#legendText" ).append(tble);
   ```
5. once HTML elements have been added to the page, initiate the maps and insert the fake features to display the symbols

   ```
   //loop legend rows and and insert the maps
   var extent = [0, 0, 32, 32];
   var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
       code: 'xkcd-image',
       units: 'pixels',
       extent: extent
   });
   for (i = 0; i < legendRows.length; i++) { 
       //target div
       var targetDiv = document.getElementById("mapLegendRowSymbolDiv" + i);
       //layer for icon
       var sourceLegend = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
       var vectorLegend = new ol.layer.Vector({
           source: sourceLegend,
           style: legendRows[i].style
       });
       //map
       var mapLegend = new ol.Map({
           controls: [],
           layers: [
               new ol.layer.Image({
                   source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                       projection: projection,
                       imageExtent: extent
                   })
               }),
               vectorLegend
           ],
           target: targetDiv,
           view: new ol.View({
               projection: projection,
               center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
               zoom: 2,
               maxZoom: 2
           })
       });
       //icon feature depending on type
       var geom;
       if(legendRows[i].geomType=='point'){
           geom = new ol.geom.Point([16,16]);
       }else if(legendRows[i].geomType=='polygon'){
           var polyCoords = [];
           polyCoords.push([15.7, 15.7]);
           polyCoords.push([16.3, 15.7]);
           polyCoords.push([16.3, 16.3]);
           polyCoords.push([15.7, 16.3]);
           polyCoords.push([15.7, 15.7]);
           geom = new ol.geom.Polygon([polyCoords]);
       }else{
           var lineCoords = [];                
           lineCoords.push([15.6, 15.6]);
           lineCoords.push([16, 16]);
           lineCoords.push([16, 15.8]);
           lineCoords.push([16.4, 16.2]);
           geom = new ol.geom.LineString(lineCoords);
       }
       var feature = new ol.Feature({
           geometry: geom
       });
       vectorLegend.getSource().addFeature(feature);
   }
   ```

With this, I was able create and update a separate Legend dialog (jQuery UI):

[image]

I haven't tested a lot yet, there may be some problems with this approach...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, OpenLayers doesn't support what you want (or at least I don't know how to do it). As Chau told you, LegendPanel from GeoExt is your only hope.

Interesting links:

http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/LegendPanel.html

http://www.mail-archive.com/openlayers-users@lists.osgeo.org/msg01318.html

Comment: That looks like what I want, but unfortunately I don't think I can move our project from jQuery to ExtJS so I won't be able to use it this time. :-(

Answer (score 2):

As one option, you could create SVG elements with same attributes like in OL3 style. Here's example for circle style (you would need similar methods also other types):

```
getIconLegend = function(style) {
    style = style.getImage();
    var radius = style.getRadius();
    var strokeWidth = style.getStroke().getWidth();
    var dx = radius + strokeWidth;

    var svgElem = $('<svg />')
        .attr({
            width: dx * 2,
            height: dx * 2
        });

    $('<circle />')
        .attr({
            cx: dx,
            cy: dx,
            r: radius,
            stroke: style.getStroke().getColor(),
            'stroke-width': strokeWidth,
            fill: style.getFill().getColor()
        })
        .appendTo(svgElem);

    // Convert DOM object to string to overcome from some SVG manipulation related oddities
    return $('<div>').append(svgElem).html();
}
```

Since SVG manipulation with jQuery is bit different from HTML elements, I'm converting object to string in return. Details can be found from [jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

Later, you can stick legend icon to HTML with

```
$('#legendText').prepend($(getIconLegend(yourFeature.getStyle())));
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get to what you want with plain OpenLayers is if you use WMS service instead of WFS or whatever method you use to fetch features. WMS has request type GetLegendGraphic that, as name suggests, lets you dynamically fetch image that shows what style is applied to layer.

Comment: I don't have a server sending me WFS, so I can't switch it to WMS. I have my own XML which is turned into features that have use an OpenLayers.Style. No other server knows about the style I am using so I really need OpenLayers to make the legend. I'm surprised that it's not built in to OL, to me it's an obvious use case.

Comment: well,then send a patch for that :)

Answer (score 0):

A half-handed legend can be made:

**For WMS features**
With a Geoserver, [GetLegendGraphic](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html) can generate an image legend for each WMS layer

**For WFS features**
For each layer, a legend can be built based on its [style](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style-Style.html) attributes:

- Fill's color (ex: `style.getFill().getColor()`)
- Stroke's attributes (ex: `style.getStroke().getColor()`)
- Image's image, which is an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), depending on the style (ex: `style.getImage().getImage()`)

Comment: doesn't work if the style is defined using a StyleFunction