# How to add a circle to svg element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I'm trying to put circles in svg dynamically. In `index.html` file I created this `svg` section.

```
<svg id="svgArea" width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

In **js** file i tried this

```
$('#svgArea').append('<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />');
```

This seems not working.

Tried the below code, but couldn't find how to apply cx, cy, r ...

```
var crcl= document.createElement("CIRCLE");
$('#svgArea').append(crcl);
```

What I am trying to achieve is dynamically create n circles on a button click. And on another button click delete buttons one by one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to work with jquery and Svg directly (no plugins)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148859/is-it-possible-to-work-with-jquery-and-svg-directly-no-plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get a solution, here is a minimal example of the approach. But for more flexibility, I would suggest to use a library. Take a look at the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwachtler/xt8nts0w/)** for a demo (You've to scroll down to see the button).

**HTML**

```
<svg id="svgArea" width="500" height="500"></svg>
<button id="addCircle">Add a circle</button>
```

**JS**

```
var x = 50;
var y = 50;
var xMax = $('#svgArea').width();
var yMax = $('#svgArea').height();

$("#addCircle").click(function () {
    var existingContent = $('#svgArea').html();
    var toInsert = '<circle cx="' + x + '" cy="' + y + '" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />';
    $('#svgArea').html(existingContent + toInsert);
    if ((x + 100) <= xMax) {
        x += 100;
    } else {
        if ((y + 100) <= yMax) {
            y += 100;
            x = 50;
        } else {
            alert("There is no place inside the canvas!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The variable x and y and boundary collision checks are not asked for and are just noise here.