# Transform GeoJSON to SVG with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, rendering, geojson

Is there a *ready-to-use* Javascript plugin that thansforms a GeoJSON string into a SVG string? A rendering engine, as [Tempo](http://tempojs.com/), or the project [JsonT](http://goessner.net/articles/jsont/) would be useful, but I need the template to make them works.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) library. Following code snippet will do the job:

Include d3.js in your html file

```
<script src="files/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Assuming,  you have div with id map in your html file:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Following js code will add map to your div map. geoJsonObj is your geojson.

```
var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(geoJsonObj.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
```

To see a working example, go [here](http://bl.ocks.org/4060606). Note that the example uses topojson as input to the .data() attribute.

Comment: Where is the variable `path` coming from in your code, on the last line?

Comment: Nevermind, I found (and updated) a complete example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425440/displaying-map-using-d3-js-and-geojson/38552478#38552478

Comment: @user568458 path is not a variable, it is an svg element, like div in html. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: `.attr("d", path);` - that's a Javascript variable, named path, being used to apply the `d` attributes to the SVG paths that D3 draws. Looking at other D3 examples I'd guess it's [D3 geo path generator object](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md) defined with something like `var path = d3.geo.path().projection( someProjectionObject );`

Answer (score 7):

There is a basic tool available to convert GeoJSON to SVG [geojson2svg](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/geojson2svg) and as an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/geojson2svg) also. As the output from geojson2svg is SVG string, this tool can be used in browser as well as with node.js.

Here is an example:

`npm install geojson2svg --save`

```js
var geojson2svg = require('geojson2svg')

var converter = geojson2svg(
   {attributes: ['properties.foo', 'properties.bar', 'properties.baz']})
var svgStr = converter.convert({
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[0,0], [1000,1000]]},
    properties: {foo: 'fooVal-1', bar: 'barVal-1', baz: 'bazVal-1'}
  }, {
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[10,10], [100,100]]},
    properties: {foo: 'fooVal-2', bar: 'barVal-2'}
  }]  
})

console.log(svgStr) 
/* output
[
  '<path d="M128,128 128.00638801979818,127.99361198020182" foo="fooVal-1" bar="barVal-1" baz="bazVal-1"/>',
  '<path d="M128.00006388019798,127.99993611980202 128.00063880197982,127.99936119802018" foo="fooVal-2" bar="barVal-2"/>'
]

*/
```

It's very easy to covert a SVG string to DOM element. This has been explained by bobince [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/713573) very nicely with JavaScript code. I have made an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parse-svg) for convenience.

Disclaimer: I am the author of geojson2svg.

Answer (score -2):

You can look into GDAL, not sure if it fully supports SVG creation, but GDAL can generally convert all geo formats into other geoformats.

See: [Link](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Javascript library or plugin and GDAL / OGR is C++.