# Can not add image inside SVG via jQuery: <image /> tag becomes <img />

Tags: jquery, svg

I want to add items in an SVG via jQuery.
I can well insert tags such as `<rect />` or `<text />` but I can not insert images with the tag `<image />`.

This tag becomes `<img />` automatically, which can not display an image in SVG:
http://jsfiddle.net/G4mJf/

How can I prevent this?
If it is impossible, is there another way to insert images in SVG using JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Try to use my jQuery hack [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792754/create-and-access-svg-tag-with-jquery/14985470#14985470][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792754/create-and-access-svg-tag-with-jquery/14985470#14985470

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should use `createElementNS()`:

```
var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','536');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','536');
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/SVG_Simple_Logo.svg');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
$('svg').append(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery alone cannot handle SVG manipulation properly, [as this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element). You should probably be using [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), or one of the hacky methods described in the link above.