# Inline SVG not rendering when created with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to programmatically create inline svg images of a row of shields.

My shield is a simple path:

```html
<path fill="red" d="M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z"></path>
```

Here is my script:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('main')
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  element.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
  element.lastChild.setAttribute('width', 400)
  element.lastChild.setAttribute('height', 400)

  // Code to add path inside svg, removed it and still didn't work
  element.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path'))
  element.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
  element.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    main {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    svg {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
  <main>
    <svg>
      <path fill="red" d="M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z"></path>
    </svg>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Copyable code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        main {
            display: flex;
        }
        svg {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <main>
        <svg>
            <path fill="red" d="M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z"></path>
        </svg>
    </main>
    <script>
        const element = document.querySelector('main')
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            element.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg'))
            element.lastChild.setAttribute('width', 400)
            element.lastChild.setAttribute('height', 400)

            // Code to add path inside svg, removed it and still didn't work
            element.lastChild.appendChild(document.createElementNS('http:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path'))
            element.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('fill', 'red')
            element.lastChild.lastChild.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z')
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first svg is being properly rendered, but my auto generated svgs are not being rendered.

Output:
[image: Sample Output]

Expected Output:
[image]

***How do I programmatically create inline svg images of a row of shields?***

Thanks in advance!

---

I've looked at:

- [JavaScript inline SVG not rendering [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455598/javascript-inline-svg-not-rendering): The answer given is to use `createElementNS`, which I'm already using.
- [Inline-SVG not rendering when generated by JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864758/inline-svg-not-rendering-when-generated-by-js): Answer talks about external svg.
- [Inline SVG in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768451/inline-svg-in-css): Answers talk about data uris to embed SVG. Not what I'm doing.
- [img src SVG changing the styles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css): Answers talk about external svgs.

Comment: You  have a typo in your namespace string: `document.createElementNS('http:http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')`. It's `'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'`.

Comment: @ccprog I CANNOT believe I missed that. Should I delete the question?

Comment: As I see it the problem here is not the typo but the way that you change the DOM. Without a reference to the element it becomes difficult to change the attributes. You could rewrite the question so that it matches the two answers.

Answer (score 3):

I can see that you are trying to create multiple SVGs, but I think it makes sense to just have on SVG and then insert all the paths in that.

I have created an array with the different sheilds (they could have more properties, here only color). And for each of them create a path. The position is controlled by the index.

```js
const svg01 = document.querySelector('#svg01');

const shields = ['red', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'green', 'orange', 'red'];

shields.forEach((color,i) => {
  let shield = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  shield.setAttribute('fill', color);
  shield.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L0 15 q0 25 20 35 q20 -10 20 -35 L40 0z');
  shield.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${i * 100 + 20} 0)`);
  svg01.appendChild(shield);
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <svg id="svg01" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  </svg>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

- SVG created as HTML tag in the DOM gets the correct namespace, no need to specify it
- to prevent more NameSpacing issues, you can add SVG content as **innerHTML**
- I used [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#) to convert your Shield to **relative** notation,
  so you don't need a `translate` to position it
- Wrapped in a native JS Web Component `<svg-shields>`, so you don't have to worry about required DOM elements

```html
<svg-shields colors="red,green,orange,red,green,orange,red,green,orange,red">
                                                                </svg-shields>
<svg-shields colors="red,yellow,blue"></svg-shields>
```

**creates:**

[image]

```js
customElements.define("svg-shields", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let colors = this.getAttribute("colors").split(",");
    this.innerHTML =
      `<svg viewBox="0 0 ${colors.length*100} 100">` +
      colors.map((fill, idx) => {
        return `<path fill="${fill}" 
                  d="M${ idx*100 + 20 } 0 l0 15q0 25 20 35 20-10 20-35l0-15z"/>`
      }).join("\n") +
      `</svg>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-shields colors="red,green,orange,red,green,orange,red,green,orange,red">
</svg-shields>

<svg-shields colors="red,yellow,blue"></svg-shields>
```