# jQuery .text() is working but not .html()

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njKzg/) of my problem.

Basically, I made a chart with d3.js. When a piece of the chart is hovered over I want the data for that piece to be displayed. I want to be able to style the data being displayed so I have it output with span's using `.html()` (can be seen on line 93 of the fiddle) but it doesn't seem to work. For some reason if I change it to `.text()` though it is changed fine, but then I have the html being displayed too.

This also needs to work in IE8, that's why `r2d3.js` has been included.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's because `SVGElement` object doesn't have `innerHTML` property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery's append not working with svg element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

Comment: `$(".totals")` is a `<text>` element. I would imaging that means it can only display text, not HTML code.

Comment: I just confirmed this with the fiddle. If you change the return line to this: `return "" + d.data.population + " " + d.data.age + "";`, the data will show up in the middle of the chart.

Comment: How come I'm able to do it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kg5yB/) though?

Comment: Because in that fiddle, your "text" element is not a descendent of an "svg" element, so it's just treated as an invalid HTML element, not an svg:text element.  Invalid HTML elements have innerHTML properties which is what d3 and jquery .html() sets, whereas svg:text elements do not have such a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this updated fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/njKzg/2/

```
$(".totals").html($(class1).html() );
```

your code need some changes..