# jQuery append converts values to lowercase

Tags: jquery, svg, append

I've been making some SVG append to my code using jQuery and I have a problem with my animation on svg element.
The thing is that when I insert this code

```
<circle fill="#2380c2" cx="20.5" cy="12.5" r="1.5" id="circ1">
<animate begin="svg_1.mouseover" end="svg_1.mouseout" from="20.5" to="20.5" dur="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="cx" values="20.5;18.5;20.5;22.5;20.5"></animate
</circle>
```

using append(), **attributeName** is converted to **attributename** and my Google Chrome doesn't recognize it as a valid attribute.

Any help on how to solve this append() issue?

Comment: Probably duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element/3642265#3642265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, jQuery isn't able to append elements from the SVG namespace by default. Try creating the element with [document.createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS). Second, jQuery's attr calls toLower on attribute names, so it wont work for camelCased attributes like SVG uses (see [this jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11166)). You can use a different library that does support SVG, like [D3](http://d3js.org/), or use the native javascript method [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute). For example:

```
svgEl = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle'));
svgEl.attr({fill: '#2380c2', cx:'20', cy:'20', r:'10'}).appendTo('#theSvg');

animateEl = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate'));
animateEl.attr({from:"10", to:"20", dur:"3s"}).appendTo('circle');
$animateEl = $("animate")[0];
$animateEl.setAttribute("attributeName", "r");
$animateEl.setAttribute("repeatCount", "indefinite");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CodyRank/7L6wX/1/

Comment: I did that already. I have a function for creating SVG: [code]function svg(element,eldict,divid) { 
   $el = $(document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null).createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', element));
   $(divid).append($el.attr(eldict));
}[/code]
but when I append attribudets they are lowercase and the animation dosen't work

Comment: And what are you passing to that function? It's difficult to help with incomplete code. Could you post a full example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Ahh, it looks like `attr` in jquery calls toLower. You'll have to use the built in setAttribute instead. I'll update my answer, but here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CodyRank/7L6wX/

Comment: Yes I got it. I used pure JS instead of jQuery and setAttribute did the job.