# Adding SVG elements to an HTML5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I am trying to add `<svg>` into an HTML5 Canvas using `jQuery`. What I have currently done is, when I click in the canvas area, I retrieve the x and y coordinates and append an SVG element.

```
var svg = "<svg><circle cx='"+x+"' cy='"+y+"' r='"+r+"' fill='red'/></svg>";
$("#canvas").append(svg);
```

The SVG seems to be added in the DOM when I check the source (using F12 in Mozilla Firefox) in the correct position (x,y), a square is highlighted in the browser window, when I hover my mouse over the added `<svg>` element in the source. But the `<svg>` is not visible.
The code looks something like this after doing 3 clicks on the HTML5 Canvas.

```
<canvas id="canvas">
    <svg><circle cx="557.8500061035156" cy="222" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
    <svg><circle cx="729.8500061035156" cy="251" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
    <svg><circle cx="517.8500061035156" cy="109" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
</canvas>
```

Can somebody help me with the problem?
I am using `<svg>` because later I want to be able to click and drag the circles rather than drawing the standard `arcs` into the 2d context canvas using javascript.

Comment: Any markup within `<canvas>` is treated as a fallback for when the browser doesn't support the Canvas API. From MDN:

    A fallback text is provided if a browser is unable to render the canvas, or if can't read a canvas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware you could use svg elements inside a canvas. Normally you either chose to use canvas or you use svg. These are 2 different technologies. Are you absolutely sure that what you are trying is possible?

Comment: well now I am currently I am using raphaeljs to do that, but most perhaps you are right that these are two different technologies

Answer (score 0):

Is there realy need for mixing canvas and svg?

```
<canvas id="canvas">
    <svg><circle cx="557.8500061035156" cy="222" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
    <svg><circle cx="729.8500061035156" cy="251" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
    <svg><circle cx="517.8500061035156" cy="109" r="20" fill="red"></circle></svg>
</canvas>
```

I suggest that you create wrapper for SVG. Like this :

```
<div id="parent">
    <svg id="content">
        <circle cx="557.8500061035156" cy="222" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="729.8500061035156" cy="251" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="517.8500061035156" cy="109" r="20" fill="red"></circle>
    </svg>    
</div>
```

then, when adding another svg element do this :

```
$("#parent").html($("#parent").html());
```

See this question for detail about that problem with not showing svg : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="forsvgtopng">
            <div id="svgelemntdiv">
               <svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                 <rect width="150" height="150" fill="rgb(0, 255, 0)" stroke-width="1" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)"/>
               </svg>
            </div>
           <div class="canvasdiv">
                <canvas ></canvas>
           </div>
        <div class="pngdiv">
             <img id="svgpng" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

call the javascript function like convertsvg('#forsvgtopng')

```
  function convertsvg(selectors) {
          [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selectors), function (div) {
            try {

                var sourceImage;
                var imgs = document.getElementById('svgpng'),
                  svg = div.querySelector('svg'),
                  can = div.querySelector('canvas'),
                  ctx = can.getContext('2d');
                  can.width =500;
                  can.height = 550;

                 sourceImage = new Image;
                sourceImage.width = can.width;
                sourceImage.height = can.height;
                sourceImage.onload = function () {
                    ctx.drawImage(sourceImage,80,90);

                    imgs.src = can.toDataURL();
                };

                sourceImage.src = svg ? svgDataURL(svg) :"";
            } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
        });
    }
```

}

```
  function svgDataURL(svg) {

        var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
        return "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the full potential of SVG I suggest this plugin. Its lot easier and developer friendly http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: I am having issues with eventlisteners. Is there any other way you could suggest?

Comment: The link seems to be dead.