# Wrapping existing inline SVG <g> element with <a> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I’d like to wrap a series of `<g>` elements with `<a>` elements so they are tabbable. I've tried using jQuery but encountered the namespace problem so have been looking at a more vanilla JS approach. The SVG was created in Illustrator and loaded into the page with an AJAX call. I then use jQuery to bind events etc. I know I can add them in Illustrator with Image Map but I’d like to find a way to get it done programmatically. This is what I’d like to do:

```
$('g').wrap(function() {
    var anchor = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a');
    anchor.setAttribute('xlink:href', 'javascript:void(0);');

    return anchor;
});
```

This gets it into the DOM but doesn't render so I'm assuming a namespace problem still. I’m more than likely doing something obviously wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here's a pure JS fiddle (same problem as code above): http://jsfiddle.net/bigwigal/pqe3o93e/.

Comment: tabbable??? What about setting `tabindex` attribute?

Comment: _HTML_ namespacing in _JavaScript_ always gives me headaches too. Looking at the generated _HTML_ in the console, then pasting that in as html into a new fiddle (no _JS_) and trying it gives me some rendered output.

Comment: It might work if you create an SVG a element (in the SVG namespace) rather than a html element, having said that using jquery with SVG is rather hit and miss.

Comment: @A.Wolff setting `tabindex` would be perfect except it isn't supported until SVG 2.0 is. Until then the `<a>` element is our only friend (unless someone else knows something that I don't, which is entirely possible).

Comment: maybe the solution over here would help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element

Comment: @errand thanks for your response. I did have a quick read of this but thought there must be a simpler way - in fact the answer below the accepted one gives this (refreshing the page/container). If only I'd read further, thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SVG `<a>` elements your content will appear and links will work.

```
var g = document.getElementById('target');

var parent = g.parentNode;
var a = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'a');

a.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'javascript:void(0);');
a.appendChild(g);

parent.appendChild(a);
```

Not sure if that will make it tabbable but if not you'll need to wrap in an html `<a>` with an `<svg>` child as directly wrapping a `<g>` won't render as you've seen. I.e. you'll need to create something that looks like this... `<foreignObject><a><svg><g></g></svg></a></foreignObject>` where the `<a>` is an html element and the others are svg elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't really solve the problem. What I'm looking for is a way to get it to work as if you copy and paste the output to a new fiddle as @Paul S. notes above, resulting in the content within being displayed and tabbable.

Comment: it does work, just took the ns declaration into the jquery fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqe3o93e/2/

Comment: That's odd, it didn't when I plumbed it into the fiddle in it's original form. It also doesn't in my full code for some reason. My  apologies anyway Robert.