# Adding an Image to svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, svg

I am trying to add an image to a certain element within a svg in Javascript. I am trying

```
$( 'g.nv-label' ).each(function(i, obj){
      $( obj ).append('<image x="20" class="klasse" y="20" width="100" 
        height="100" xlink:href="http://goo.gl/IkKMb5" />');
    });
```

... which does not show my element.

If i try

```
$( 'g.nv-label' ).each(function(i, obj){  
      $( obj ).append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "http://goo.gl/IkKMb5")
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("class", "klasse");
 });
```

it adds the element, but not as a `<img>`, but as `<g>` (which does not show my image defined in the href).

Can anyone tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from jQuery, which interprets your [svg `<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag) into [html `<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) element.

jQuery is designed for html, not svg, some operations like `append()` may fail.
[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

You should rather prefer some library like [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) which will allow you to `append('image')`.

```js
d3.selectAll("g.nv-label").append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", "20")
  .attr("y", "20")
  .attr("class", "klasse")
  .attr("width", "100")
  .attr("height", "100")
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://goo.gl/IkKMb5");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(0,0)"  ></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(120,0)"></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(240,0)"></g>
</svg>
```

Or vanilla javascript :

```js
var g = document.querySelectorAll('g.nv-label');
for (i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
  var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
  el.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', "http://goo.gl/IkKMb5");
  el.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '100');
  el.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '100');
  el.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 20);
  el.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 20);
  g[i].appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(0,0)"></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(120,0)"></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(240,0)"></g>
</svg>
```

Or, if you really want to use jQuery, this workaround seems to work since jQuery 1.4:

```js
$( 'g.nv-label' ).each(function(i, obj){
      $( obj ).html($( obj ).html()+'<image x="20" class="klasse" y="20" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://goo.gl/IkKMb5" ></image>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="200">
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(0,0)"></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(120,0)"></g>
  <g class="nv-label" transform="translate(240,0)"></g>
</svg>
```