# innerHTML does not work in IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg

i have IE 10 and i have svg image. In svg I put TEXT element with

```
var newElement = function(name, attr) {
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  
var tmp = document.createElementNS(svgNS, name);
for (k in attr) {
    if (k === 'style') {
        for (s in attr[k]) {
            tmp.style[s] = attr[k][s]; 
        }
    } else if (k === 'innerHTML') {
        console.log('Break 1('+typeof(attr[k])+')'+ attr[k]);
        console.log('Break 2: '+tmp.innerHTML);
        tmp.innerHTML = attr[k];
        console.log('Break 3: '+tmp.innerHTML);
    } else {
        tmp.setAttributeNS(null, k, attr[k]);
    }
}

console.log('Break 4: ');
console.log(tmp);
return tmp;
```

};

And i cant see placed text in IE only. In FF and Chrome it works correctly.
In source i can see empty text element, but text element have attributes.

It's log from IE Console:

```
Break 1(string)Coś tam Marzec: 158
Break 2: undefined
Break 3: Coś tam Marzec: 158
Break 4: 
<text id="1135198_point_2_desc" font-size="11" visibility="hidden" text-anchor="middle" x="204.8182" y="209.68"></text>
```

Firefox console:

```
Break 1(string)Legenda Pionowa
svg.html (wiersz 50)
Break 2:
svg.html (wiersz 51)
Break 3: Legenda Pionowa
svg.html (wiersz 53)
Break 4:
svg.html (wiersz 59)
<text x="0" y="130" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(-90, 20, 130)">
```

And in firefox text is inside TEXT element

Comment: OK, but what question are you asking?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element). Basically it boils down to `innerHTML` being a member of `HTMLElement`. The fact that it works in Chrome/Firefox is because they have added this non-standard method to `SVGElement`.

Comment: Untrue that it's non-standard: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html says it's on Element and SVGElement derives from Element (as does HTMLElement) also untrue that we've added it to SVGElement (we added it to Element as the standard tells us to)

Comment: I deal a lot with intranet/corp. users so forgive me if this is not you...I see it all the time in my world. You are using IE10, but is your browser running IE10? Hit F12 and look up your document mode. Guessing it's forced to compatibility or IE8, so SVG not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem. I used https://code.google.com/p/innersvg/
and I replaced innerHTML to innerSVG