# jquery appended html is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I tried to empty a svg and append some it's inner divs back, it doesn't work but can see the html parts are loaded in the browser in faded colour. When i edited it in the browser and add it back it works.

The div part,

```
<li class="chart">
    <svg id="lineChartSVG" class="lineChart--svg">
       <defs>
           <linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
                            <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" />
                            <stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" />
            </linearGradient>
         </defs>
     </svg>               
 </li>
```

this is the way i did,

```
$('#lineChartSVG').empty();
 var html = ' <defs> <linearGradient id=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea\" x1=\"0\" x2=\"0\" y1=\"0\" y2=\"1\"> <stop class=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top\" offset=\"0%\" /> <stop class=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom\" offset=\"100%\" /> </linearGradient> </defs>';
 $('#lineChartSVG').append(html);
 inFlightRequestCountChart();
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: I remember some problems with jQuery ans svg I had once. Problem was jQuery treats attributes not as case sensitive, but svg requires case sensitive attributes. Maybe check on that.

Comment: Is that all the jQuery you're using?

Comment: why don't you simply use `li` element to insert html and re initiate chart instance. if problem occur for chart

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/4772988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the SVG element is not updated dynamically. It should update once you refreshed your container element. In this case `<li>` i.e. give it `id='chart1'`, but I suggest to use a specified (by you) container for it.

```
$("#chart1").html($("#chart1").html());
```

Explanation: [jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element/3642265#13654655)

Example: http://jsbin.com/ejifab/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Please Try also, to empty the contents of the tag.

```
 $('#lineChartSVG').text('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `html()` like this.

```
$('#lineChartSVG').empty();
var html = ' <defs> <linearGradient id=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea\" x1=\"0\" x2=\"0\" y1=\"0\" y2=\"1\"> <stop class=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top\" offset=\"0%\" /> <stop class=\"lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom\" offset=\"100%\" /> </linearGradient> </defs>';
$('#lineChartSVG').html(html);
inFlightRequestCountChart();
```