# How to add a SVG element at runtime - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'm going to add a SVG element by clicking a button:

```
myApp.directive('addRectangle', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('click',function() {
            scope.rectCount++;
            angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('svgMain')).append('<circle r=5 cx=200 cy=200 fill=red data-scope='+scope.rectCount +' />');


        });
    }
});
```

The element will be added correctly as I expect, but the problem is it is not showing in the related position! I've checked the source html of the page and I'm completely sure about that.
This is the fiddle of this question: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fp4yfwx1/1/)

In addition, I'm using `angular` version `1.4.x`.

Comment: Presumably the append is putting data in the wrong namespace similar to this jquery issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element

Comment: @RobertLongson I add xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attribute to both svg and circle element but there is no difference in the result.

Comment: There wouldn't be. You need to use createElementNS ideally or if not innerHtml will work in many (but not all UAs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @RobertLongson said in the comment of the question you should mention `SVG` namespace in each and every time you want to add a new `SVG` element, like this sample:

```
function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
            var el= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
            for (var k in attrs)
                el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
            return el;
        }
```

You can use this function in order to add a new `SVG` element. Also I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/2t630Lc4/).