# Dynamically added SVG g tags are not showing

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I dynamically added `circle` tags in `g` tag using `jQuery.append()` and got the following result.(server side language is php)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttn43pkr/)

However, the circles are not displayed when I load it from my local server.
Specifically, browser does not display circles in g tag at first load, then when I copy the part of `g` tag from chrome developer tool and paste it to separate html file (or jsfiddle etc.), it shows correctly.

What is the problem?

This is the JS code:

```
    var dataset = new Array();

    <?php
     // data is added to dataset
    ?>

    var day = dataset[dataset.length - 1].date - dataset[0].date + 1;

    for(var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++){
        var count = dataset[i].date - dataset[0].date; 

        if(dataset[i].like == true) $('g.like').append("<circle  cx='"+ (count * 100) + "' cy='" + dataset[i].num/max * 300 +"' r = '4.5'  fill='red'>s</circle>");
        else $('g.dislike').append("<circle  cx='"+ (count * 100) + "' cy='" + dataset[i].num/max * 300 +"' r = '4.5'  fill='red'>s</circle>");
        }
```

Comment: what is the DOCTYPE that you are using have you declared that you will be using svg in your html?

Comment: your fiddle doesn't contain javascript

Comment: Where is **Dynamically added svg g tags** code??

Comment: @RolandStarke I just copied the result of javascript code

Comment: @vssadineni `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">

Comment: are creating `svg` dynamically too??

Comment: those dynamically generated tags must be read by browser, as your browser is expecting html. all you have to do is declare that you will be using html + svg in your document.

Comment: @ozil `svg` tag and `g` tag are not dynamically created.

Comment: just try by changing the <html> with what I shared with you in earlier comment and check.

Comment: @ozil sadly it changes nothing...

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that really show how you are dynamically inserting these `g` tags (in your snippet, they are inserted in the HTML, not with js).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction

Comment: @soonoo can you add some sample data to `dataset ` as well

Comment: @ozil http://jsfiddle.net/rdk2kqbd/ I have about 10~20 objects in dataset

Comment: @ozil sorry please switch `dataset.add()` to `dataset.push()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vssadineni/45fzzmw3/ I hope this might help you.

Comment: for detailed explanation   http://blag.oztechninja.com/post/25699330571/simple-svg-manipulation-with-jquery

Comment: @vssadineni Thank you!!!!!! It seems working

Comment: You are welcome.! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that SVG elements are different from HTML elements.
jQuery only creates HTML elements.
This problem has already been discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element).
Here is a working solution that makes use of the `makeSVG` function that has been proposed (blue circles are added with JavaScript).
Notice that I didn't used at all jQuery as it is superfluous here.

```js
function makeSVGEl(tag, attrs) {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs) {
      el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    }
    return el;
}

var dataset = [
  { x: 100, y: 33  },
  { x: 200, y: 133 },
  { x: 300, y: 100 },
  { x: 400, y: 100 },
  { x: 500, y: 100 },
  { x: 600, y: 100 }
];

var svg = document.querySelector("svg.progress-chart");
var g = makeSVGEl("g", { class: "dislike" });
svg.appendChild(g);

dataset.forEach(function(coords){
  g.appendChild(makeSVGEl("circle", {
    cx: coords.x,
    cy: coords.y,
    fill: "blue",
    r: 4.5
  }));
});
```

```html
<svg class="progress-chart" width="600" height="400">
    <g class="like">
        <circle cx="0" cy="266.66666666666663" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="200" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="200" cy="233.33333333333334" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="300" cy="200" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="400" cy="133.33333333333331" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="500" cy="166.66666666666669" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="600" cy="300" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
        <circle cx="700" cy="33.33333333333333" r="4.5" fill="red"></circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: and how would this be done without JQuery. I have a hunch JQuery would not be needed at all.

Comment: @AndrewS there is no jQuery involved in my snippet

Comment: Thanks for this. Couldnt understand what was the problem createElementNS solved