# Vue Js: Invisible SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vue.js

I've tried to append a line to a svg element but even though the line exists in DOM, it's not visible.

```
    <svg id="app">
      <svg-line></svg-line>
    </svg>
    <template id="svg-lineTemp">
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"></line>
    </template>
    <script>
    Vue.component('svg-line', {
      template: '#svg-lineTemp'
    });
    vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app'
    });
  </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/omidh/4xmha7om/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently only the script tag works, the reason is still unknown:

```
<script id="svg-lineTemp" type="text/x-template">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100"></line>
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqg8b8zb/

### UPDATE:

If you look inside vue.js you will find this

```
function nodeToFragment(node) {
// if its a template tag and the browser supports it,
// its content is already a document fragment.
if (isRealTemplate(node)) {
  trimNode(node.content);
  return node.content;
}
// script template
if (node.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
  return stringToFragment(node.textContent);
}
...
```

This still doesn't explain why modifying the DOM doesn't result in a change of the SVG, but that is part of the browser logic.

Comment: `template` is a standard tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template Still upvoted, as your solution works.

Comment: You are right, I should investigate further why your solution didn't work then.

Comment: Thanks for solution, Also Vuejs would throw "Unregistered Component" error if <circle> tag is used in template tag

Comment: It's another clue that points to the fact that vue tries to interpret standard HTML5 tags as components, but to be sincere, even `<div>` instead of `<template>` wouldn't work. I haven't looked at the code yet, but I suspect there is some special pleading towards the script tag.

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here's the Vue issue ticket on it.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2661

Make sure that this is not just a Chrome issue you are encountering.  The `<script type="x/template">` is a valid workaround for the issue.