# overflow issue in chrome and opera

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, overflow, opera

i have a problem with `overflow` on `0px` `height` `width` elements in new versions

my source code ([**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qd8g3h91/1/))

code worked nice before, but i have this problem in latest chrome and opera (not in firefox and edge)

css:

```
.cssload-dots {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    filter: url(#goo);
        -o-filter: url(#goo);
        -ms-filter: url(#goo);
        -webkit-filter: url(#goo);
        -moz-filter: url(#goo);
}
```

when i change `width` and `height` to `200px` , everything works nice...

but i can't change this...

because i used this code on all of my website pages and if i change that, maybe it damage all other parts

**edit:**

when i disable filter by inspect element, everything be ok...

maybe svg filter have a problem but i don't know anything about svg

**edit:**

i changed svg, it's be better but not enough

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="goo">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="12" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a bug in google chrome...

i reported that and it will fix in new versions