# how to add a html title (tooltip) to a leaflet.js polygon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I have a [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) map and I would like to add a html title (tooltip) to my polygon. If I use plain JQuery:

```
$('<title>my tooltip</title>').appendTo()
```

The title gets added to the DOM but is not visible. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element) for more details but if I follow that solution, I can no longer use the leaflet features.

I also tried the [leaflet.label](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label) plugin but the label moves around with the mouse pointer. I just want the standard browser title tooltip that appears in one position shortly after on hover)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Leaflet 1.0.0 has a new built-in [`L.tooltip`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip) class that deprecates the Leaflet.label plugin. The tooltip points at the shape center and does not move with the mouse.

```js
L.polygon(coords).bindTooltip("my tooltip").addTo(map);
```

Demo:

```js
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

//L.circle([48.85, 2.35], {radius: 1000}).bindTooltip("test").addTo(map);
L.rectangle([
  [48.84, 2.34],
  [48.86, 2.36]
]).bindTooltip("test").addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

---

To address OP's comment about tooltip being displayed at the polygon center, which can be out of view when the polygon is very big and current zoom is high, you can use the [`sticky`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip-sticky) option:

```js
L.polygon(coords).bindTooltip("my tooltip", {
  sticky: true // If true, the tooltip will follow the mouse instead of being fixed at the feature center.
}).addTo(map);
```

Updated demo:

```js
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

//L.circle([48.85, 2.35], {radius: 1000}).bindTooltip("test").addTo(map);
L.rectangle([
  [48.84, 2.34],
  [48.86, 2.36]
]).bindTooltip("test", {
  sticky: true
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: oh thanks, It looks good but my polygon (well, rectangle) is the full size of the map. It seems the tooltip gets lost somewhere

Comment: Added `sticky` option to address above issue.

Comment: Also as a side note, I did not want the arrow for the tooltip on the shape, so centering it using `direction: 'center'` put the label in the middle without an arrow