# D3: Cannot append simple path to svg container

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am not succeding in appending a path on a simple svg container.
It considers my "path" element as a text instead.

Here is my code:

```js
// Create the SVG
var tracer = {};
tracer.$container = document.getElementById('container');

tracer.$svg = $('<svg class="svg-d3-table" style="width:100%; height:100%">');
tracer.$container.append(tracer.$svg);

// Specify the path points
var pathInfo = [{x:0, y:60},
                {x:50, y:110},
                {x:90, y:70},
                {x:140, y:100}];

// Specify the function for generating path data             
var pathLine = d3.line()
                 .x(function(d){return d.x;})
                 .y(function(d){return d.y;})
                 .curve(d3.curveBasis); 

// Append path
tracer.$svg.append("path")
           .attr("d", pathLine(pathInfo))
           .attr("stroke", "white")
           .attr("stroke-width", 8)
           .attr("fill", "none");
```

Instead of having a new path element as

```js
<path d="M314,352L314,352C314,352,314,352,..."></path>
```

It comes with the following:

```js
<svg class="svg-d3-table" style="..." d="M0,60L8.3,68.3.7,...">path</svg>
```

What am I missing?

PS: Sorry, I come from c++ and can be struggled with some very basic js operations.

Thank you very much.
Kind Regards.

Comment: Don't use jQuery when messing around with SVG. It is not meant to handle the SVG namespace and is likely to be the source of many headaches. The following describes your problem in much more detail: [*"jquery's append not working with svg element?"*](/q/3642035).

Comment: This mix of d3, jQuery and vanilla js is so awkward and confusing... Why don't you create the SVG using d3 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, avoid mixing `jquery` and `d3`.

The root of your problems though is that your `tracer.$svg` is a **jquery selector** but you are treating it as a **`d3` selector**.  While both of them have an `append` method, they are two wholly different beasts (and as @altocumulus points out, jquery don't play so nice manipulatively SVG).

Here's your code as I would write it with just `d3`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="background-color: steelblue"></div>
  <script>
    // Create the SVG
    var tracer = {};
    tracer.$container = d3.select('#container');

    tracer.$svg = tracer.$container.append("svg")
      .attr("class", "svg-d3-table")
      .style("width", "100%")
      .style("height", "100%");

    // Specify the path points
    var pathInfo = [{
      x: 0,
      y: 60
    }, {
      x: 50,
      y: 110
    }, {
      x: 90,
      y: 70
    }, {
      x: 140,
      y: 100
    }];

    // Specify the function for generating path data             
    var pathLine = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      })
      .curve(d3.curveBasis);

    // Append path
    tracer.$svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", pathLine(pathInfo))
      .attr("stroke", "white") //<-- need a color?
      .attr("stroke-width", 8)
      .attr("fill", "none");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to altocumulus:

[jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)
Is exactly the kind of information I was looking for better understanding of manipulating DOM (but still shows me how much front-end development can be akward).

Thank to Gerardo Furtado:

Indeed the need of different lib leads easily to confusing behavior and makes JS hard to handle when working on an existing project (how to determine namespace by reading code, avoid collision...)

I handled my problem by only managing my svg using D3 as you adviced:

```js
tracer.$svg = tracer.capsule.$svg = d3.select("#" + tracer.defaultName)
                                        .append("svg")
                                        .attr("width", "100%")
                                        .attr("height", "100%")
                                        .attr("id", tracer.defaultName + "-svg")
                                        .attr("class", "svg-d3-table")
                                        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
```

Thank you for your comments.