# svg not updated when using jquery .appendTo

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, svg

Chrome and Firefox don't visually update svg after adding an element with jQuery :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >
      </svg>
      <script>
         jQuery('<circle/>', {
                 r: "25",
                 cx: "80",
                 cy: "80"
              }).appendTo('svg');
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Element  is visible and editable in devTools but it appears only after inserting a space in the tag.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, jQuery is made for handling HTML elements and can't deal with svg. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642265/263832) for a more detailed explanation. You need to use plain javascript to manipulate the DOM as [demonstrated here](http://softwareas.com/ajaxjavascript-8-ways-to-create-graphics-on-the-fly/):

```
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];  //Get the first svg element
var shape = svg.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", 80);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", 80);
shape.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  25);
```

But a cool alternative that can help with this if you're doing a lot of SVG manipulation is [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) Using Snap.svg you could, instead, create it like this:

```
var s = Snap("svg");
var circle = s.circle(80, 80, 25);
```

Comment: For completeness sake, `svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Comment: Thanks. I edited to replace `svgns`.