# Browser Not Rendering Dynamically Created SVG HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am using JavaScript to dynamically create an SVG doughnut chart.

The empty SVG element is added to the page by the following code:

```js
//Create the svg element
        var element = document.createElementNS(
          'https://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
          'svg'
        );
        element.setAttribute('id', graphName);
        element.setAttribute('height', parentHeight);
        element.setAttribute('width', parentWidth);
        element.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

        //Add the SVG element to the page
        $(".circle-navigation[data-graphName='" + graphName + "']").after(
          element
        );
```

An object, which contains all of the necessary code to draw the chart, is then instantiated. A single method, `Draw`, is then called.

Here is an example of the HTML code that the `Draw` method might generate:

```html
<svg id="982385" height="470" width="470" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M235 0 A235 235 0 0 1 401.17009357883865 68.82990642116133 L235 235 Z" fill="#262626"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="255.9537377371974" y="80.2588732398984">1. Designing</tspan>
      <tspan x="253.9537377371974" y="98.2588732398984">assessments</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M401.17009357883865 68.82990642116133 A235 235 0 0 1 470 234.99999999999997 L235 235 Z" fill="#393939"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="340.24112676010157" y="160.0462622628026">2. Setting an</tspan>
      <tspan x="357.24112676010157" y="178.0462622628026">holding</tspan>
      <tspan x="338.74112676010157" y="196.0462622628026">assessments</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M470 234.99999999999997 A235 235 0 0 1 401.17009357883865 401.17009357883865 L235 235 Z" fill="#4c4c4c"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="341.74112676010157" y="279.9537377371974">3. Preparing</tspan>
      <tspan x="333.24112676010157" y="297.9537377371974">and supporting</tspan>
      <tspan x="353.24112676010157" y="315.9537377371974">students</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M401.17009357883865 401.17009357883865 A235 235 0 0 1 235.00000000000003 470 L235 235 Z" fill="#5f5f5f"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="262.4537377371974" y="369.74112676010157">4. Marking</tspan>
      <tspan x="253.9537377371974" y="387.74112676010157">assessments</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M235.00000000000003 470 A235 235 0 0 1 68.82990642116135 401.1700935788387 L235 235 Z" fill="#737373"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="138.04626226280263" y="369.74112676010157">5. Providing</tspan>
      <tspan x="146.54626226280263" y="387.74112676010157">feedback</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M68.82990642116135 401.1700935788387 A235 235 0 0 1 0 235.00000000000006 L235 235 Z" fill="#868686"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="59.25887323989846" y="289.95373773719746">6. Results</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M0 235.00000000000006 A235 235 0 0 1 68.8299064211613 68.82990642116138 L235 235 Z" fill="#999999"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="49.75887323989838" y="155.0462622628027">7. Examining</tspan>
      <tspan x="55.25887323989838" y="173.0462622628027">boards and</tspan>
      <tspan x="65.25887323989838" y="191.0462622628027">external</tspan>
      <tspan x="57.75887323989838" y="209.0462622628027">examiners</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <path d="M68.8299064211613 68.82990642116138 A235 235 0 0 1 234.99999999999994 0 L235 235 Z" fill="#acacac"></path>
    <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="14">
      <tspan x="136.04626226280251" y="80.25887323989846">8. Reflecting</tspan>
      <tspan x="132.04626226280251" y="98.25887323989846">and reviewing</tspan>
    </text>
  </a>
  <circle cx="235" cy="235" r="94" fill="white"></circle>
</svg>
```

The code is inserted into the DOM when as it becomes available. More specifically, the code follows the following process when generating and inserting segments to the chart:

Repeat, for every segment and label required

1. Generate segment code
2. Add segment code to page
3. Generate label
4. Add label to page

The generated HTML should render. However, it does not. After the page has loaded, my output is the following:

The Broken Output:

> [image: The Broken Output]

Any advice and help on this would be very much appreciated.

Note, this question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element) as my issue is not with appending code to the DOM, it is rendering it.

Comment: I can see a pic chart rendering. What is the expectation ?

Comment: @rach8garg The expectation is that the browser will render the HTML as it does when you click 'Run code snippet' on the HTML in the question. However, it does not and instead shows hyperlinked text of each label. An example of this is shown in the last picture within the question.

Comment: Instead of `setAttribute`, you may need to use `setAttributeNS`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks. I'll try putting that in now. Although, I've never properly understood: what does the 'NS' part mean?

Comment: I copied the svg code and pasted in a local file. Saved as an SVG. It renders fine. And by the way in your first snippet, graphName is not defined.

Comment: @rach8garg graphName is not defined because it was not included in the question, as it is not a dependent for an answer. However, graphName will always contain an integer. Also, I am aware that it renders fine when pasted into a local file: this is my problem. When the code is generated and added to the page through JavaScript, it returns the broken output. I apologise if I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: It is a duplicate, using jquery does that, it appends but the code doesn't render.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think @Matt is appending an entire `svg` element to his document, not appending a sub-element to an existing SVG (Like the linked question) which seems like a different problem to me. Though a small working example would definitely help clear this up.

Comment: @DBS indeed he is and he's doing it via jQuery which doesn't work in either case. jquery + SVG generally = disaster.

Comment: Seems plausible to me, working on the latest stable jQuery on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/tLt9gzmh/1/ (Click the output window to append the `svg`)

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed. My apologies! This question is a duplicate. It is possible to append elements to an existing SVG element in the document (through the method described in the linked question). My issue was that I was trying to add the namespace over HTTPS in my project and didn't realize, but for whatever reason the code I included in the question didn't have this issue. Now that I have changed it to HTTP, it is working fine.