# Mouseover issue with title tag

Tags: javascript, svg, title

When the title tag is appended dynamically with text, the title tag content is not showing dynamically in mouseover of the text, but if the same title tag is given in code (statically) it is working fine.

Can any one help me out here?

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
  <script>
    function appendTitle() {
      try {
        var node = document.createElement("title");
        node.innerText = "I love SVG";
        document.getElementById("abcd").appendChild(node);
      } catch (e) {

      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg height="30" width="200">
        <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" id="abcd">

        I love SVG!
        </text>
        </svg>
  <button onclick="appendTitle()">click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: write the same in question and update it with proper formatting so that others can help you out

Comment: did u get my question..when u check the code?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to refresh the entire SVG for this: `document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML = document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

Comment: The answers to linked question are about jQuery, but they apply just as well for plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. SVG elements must be created in the SVG namespace with createElementNS, you've actually created a HTML title element.
2. SVG elements don't support innerText, you want textContent. Even better textContent works on HTML elements too.

```js
function appendTitle(){
    try{
        var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "title");
        node.textContent = "I love SVG";
                document.getElementById("abcd").appendChild(node); 
    }catch(e){

    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg height="30" width="200">
    <text x="0" y="15" fill="red" id="abcd">

    I love SVG!
    </text>
    </svg>
    <button onclick="appendTitle()">click</button>
</body>
```