# jQuery Rendering SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I realize this has been asked before, but the answer in [jquery's append not working with svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element)

doesn't seem to be working in my case. I attempted to do the second answer since it seems to be widely accepted as working.

My goal is go append a svg progress circle to every div element with a circlechart class. I thought that if I made a function that renders the html as a string, then it would be a sufficient workaround, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I use jQuery to dynamically add a svg element to a page?

```
function makesvg(){
  var svg = $("<svg/>")
                .addClass("circle-chart")
                .attr("viewbox", "0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862")
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  var background = $("<circle/>")
                      .addClass("circle-chart__background")
                      .attr("cx", "16.9")
                      .attr("cy", "16.9")
                      .attr("r", "15.9");
  var circle = $("<circle/>")
                  .addClass("circle-chart__circle",
                            "success-stroke")
                  .attr("cx", "16.9")
                  .attr("cy", "16.9")
                  .attr("r", "15.9")
                  .attr("stroke-dasharray", "100,100");
  var g = $("<g/>")
              .addClass("circle-chart__info")
              .append(
                $("<text/>")
                  .addClass("circle-chart__percent")
                  .attr("x", "17.9")
                  .attr("y", "15.5")
                  .text("100%")
              );
  return svg.append(background, circle, g).html()
}
/*
var svg = '<svg class="circle-chart" viewbox="0 0 33.83098862 33.83098862" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
     + '<circle class="circle-chart__background" cx="16.9" cy="16.9" r="15.9" />'
     + '<circle class="circle-chart__circle success-stroke" stroke-dasharray="100,100" cx="16.9" cy="16.9" r="15.9" />'
     + '<g class="circle-chart__info">'
     + '   <text class="circle-chart__percent" x="17.9" y="15.5">100%</text>'
     + ' </g>'
     + '</svg>'; */


(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.circlechart = function() {

        this.each(function() {
            $( this ).html(makesvg());
            $(this).html(this.html());
        });
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));


$('.circlechart').circlechart();
```

Here's my almost functional CodePen:
https://codepen.io/killia15/pen/xYVERv

It works if I just use a string, but not if I use the function.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the solution outlined in the question you linked to. Other than reiteratin jquery append does not work and referring you to that question and its answer again what are we to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few changes, your approach will work:

1. `makesvg`

   ```
    // dimensions on the svg element
    svg = $('<svg version="1.1" height="25%" width="25%" />')
    //...
    // Return svg element without serialisation
    return svg.append(background, circle, g);
   ```
2. jQuery extension

   ```
   (function( $ ) {

   $.fn.circlechart = function() {

       this.each(function() {
           $(this).append(makesvg()); // append the svg tree without serializing  
           //moved out of the loop: $(this).html(this.html());

       });
       $(this).html($(this).html()); // moved from inside the loop
       return this;
   };

   }( jQuery ));
   ```

See the live example on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5Ljek1k7/2/)