# document.getElementById vs jQuery $()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is this:

```
var contents = document.getElementById('contents');
```

The same as this:

```
var contents = $('#contents');
```

Given that jQuery is loaded?

Comment: is this proven somewhere?

Comment: @torazaburo Actually, jQuery version is not even 3 times slower (at least at latest Chrome). See: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski in that link the jquery version is 10 times slower. 26mil vs 2.4mil

Comment: Correct updated link for JSPerf is: https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/
In my case (FF 58) it's 1000 times slower. Anyway, jQuery still performs 2.5 millions ops per second. In general that's not a problem, and it certainly cannot be compared in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 1153, accepted):

Not exactly!!

```
document.getElementById('contents'); //returns a HTML DOM Object

var contents = $('#contents');  //returns a jQuery Object
```

---

In jQuery, to get the same result as `document.getElementById`, you can access the jQuery Object and get the first element in the object (Remember JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays).

```
var contents = $('#contents')[0]; //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

Comment: For anyone interested `document.getElementBy` doesn't work correctly in <IE8.  It also gets elements by `name` therefore you could theoretically argue `document.getElementById` is not only misleading, but can return incorrect values.  I think @John new this, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to add it in.

Comment: Take care if your identifier is not fixed. `$('#'+id)[0]` is not equal to `document.getElementById(id)` because `id` may contain characters which are treated special in jQuery!

Comment: This was very helpful - never knew this! I'm sure I've actually _used_ it before, though, which is what baffles me. Hey, you learn something every day! Thanks!

Comment: google `jquery equivalent of document.getelementbyid` and the first result is this post. thank you!!!

Comment: `$('#contents')[0].id` returns id name.

Comment: Is it possible to get jquery object from DOM object?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen you can turn any DOM element into a jQuery Object.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625936/how-can-i-convert-a-dom-element-to-a-jquery-element

Comment: Usefull. I used it in side each() loop function. eg. $(this)[0]

Comment: For completeness, to get the DOM object you can use the get(...) method of a jQuery object, but is slower: 

1
$( "#foo" ).get( 0 ); // Identical to $( "#foo" )[0], only slower.

Source: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Answer (score 156):

No.

Calling `document.getElementById('id')` will return a raw DOM object.

Calling `$('#id')` will return a jQuery object that wraps the DOM object and provides jQuery methods.

Thus, you can only call jQuery methods like `css()` or `animate()` on the `$()` call.

You can also write `$(document.getElementById('id'))`, which will return a jQuery object and is equivalent to `$('#id')`.

You can get the underlying DOM object from a jQuery object by writing `$('#id')[0]`.

Comment: Do you happen to know which one is faster - $(document.getElementById('element')) vs $('#element')?

Comment: @IvanIvković: The first one is faster, since it doesn't involve string parsing.

Comment: @SLaks What is the main difference between raw DOM object and jQuery object? Just that using jQuery object we have  ability to apply jQuery methods ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: They're different objects.  jQuery objects wrap DOM objects.  See the documentation.

Comment: This doc [JavaScript DOM Objects vs. jQuery Objects](https://howtodoinjava.com/jquery/javascript-dom-objects-vs-jquery-objects/) looks useful. `In one sentence, DOM objects are the objects that the web browser is using to render elements on the web page whereas jQuery objects are basically wrapper objects around a set of DOM elements.`

Comment: This helped me, 13 years later. Thanks

Answer (score 36):

A note on the difference in speed.  Attach the following snipet to an onclick call:

```
function myfunc()
{
    var timer = new Date();
    
        for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            //document.getElementById('myID');
            $('#myID')[0];
        }
    

    console.log('timer: ' + (new Date() - timer));
}
```

Alternate commenting one out and then comment the other out.  In my tests,

> document.getElementbyId averaged about **35ms** (fluctuating from `25ms` up to `52ms` on about `15 runs`)

On the other hand, the

> jQuery averaged about **200ms** (ranging from `181ms` to `222ms` on about `15 runs`).
>
> From this simple test you can see that the jQuery took about **6 times** as long.

Of course, that is over `10000` iterations so in a simpler situation I would probably use the jQuery for ease of use and all of the other cool things like `.animate` and `.fadeTo`.  But yes, technically `getElementById` is quite a bit **faster**.

Comment: Thank for this answer. I wanted to ask, should I replace all the `$('#someID')`  with `document.getElementById("someID")`    ?  I am working on something in which I have extensively used `$('#someID')` and my page runs slow for big file inputs. Please suggest me what should be my move.

Comment: If you are reusing the same one several times in the same scope then save it, like `var $myId = $('#myId');` and reuse the saved variable `$myId`.  Finding by id is generally a pretty fast thing though so if the page is sluggish there is probably a different reason.

Answer (score 35):

Close, but not the same. They're getting the same element, but the jQuery version is wrapped in a jQuery object.

The equivalent would be this

```
var contents = $('#contents').get(0);
```

or this

```
var contents = $('#contents')[0];
```

These will pull the element out of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 17):

No. The first returns a DOM element, or null, whereas the second always returns a jQuery object. The jQuery object will be empty if no element with the id of `contents` was matched.

The DOM element returned by `document.getElementById('contents')` allows you to do things such as change the `.innerHTML` (or `.value`) etc, however you'll need to use [jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com) on the jQuery Object.

```
var contents = $('#contents').get(0);
```

Is more equivilent, however if no element with the id of `contents` is matched, `document.getElementById('contents')` will return null, but `$('#contents').get(0)` will return undefined.

One benefit on using the jQuery object is that you won't get any errors if no elements were returned, as an object is always returned. However you will get errors if you try to perform operations on the `null` returned by `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 15):

No, actually the same result would be:

```
$('#contents')[0]
```

jQuery does not know how many results would be returned from the query.  What you get back is a special jQuery object which is a collection of all the controls that matched the query.

Part of what makes jQuery so convenient is that MOST methods called on this object that look like they are meant for one control, are actually in a loop called on all the members int he collection

When you use the [0] syntax you take the first element from the inner collection.  At this point you get a DOM object

Answer (score 12):

In case someone else hits this... Here's another difference:

If the id contains characters that are not supported by the HTML standard (see SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)) then jQuery may not find it even if getElementById does.

This happened to me with an id containing "/" characters (ex: id="a/b/c"), using Chrome:

```
var contents = document.getElementById('a/b/c');
```

was able to find my element but:

```
var contents = $('#a/b/c');
```

did not.

Btw, the simple fix was to move that id to the name field. JQuery had no trouble finding the element using:

```
var contents = $('.myclass[name='a/b/c']);
```

Answer (score 6):

`var contents = document.getElementById('contents');`

`var contents = $('#contents');`

The code snippets are not the same. first one returns a `Element` object ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)).
The second one, jQuery equivalent will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element. ([jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)). Internally jQuery uses `document.getElementById()` for efficiency.

In both the cases if more than one element found only the first element will be returned.

---

When checking the github project for jQuery I found following line snippets which seems to be using document.getElementById codes (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js line 68 onwards)

```
// HANDLE: $(#id)
} else {
    elem = document.getElementById( match[2] );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like most people have said, the main difference is the fact that it is wrapped in a jQuery object with the jQuery call vs the raw DOM object using straight JavaScript. The jQuery object will be able to do other jQuery functions with it of course but, if you just need to do simple DOM manipulation like basic styling or basic event handling, the straight JavaScript method is always a tad bit faster than jQuery since you don't have to load in an external library of code built on JavaScript. It saves an extra step.

Answer (score 5):

One other difference: `getElementById` returns the *first* match, while `$('#...')` returns a collection of matches - yes, the same ID can be repeated in an HTML doc.

Further, `getElementId` is called from the document, while `$('#...')` can be called from a selector. So, in the code below, `document.getElementById('content')` will return the entire body but `$('form #content')[0]` will return inside of the form.

```
<body id="content">
   <h1>Header!</h1>
   <form>
      <div id="content"> My Form </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

It might seem odd to use duplicate IDs, but if you are using something like Wordpress, a template or plugin might use the same id as you use in the content. The selectivity of jQuery could help you out there.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is built over JavaScript. This means that it's just javascript anyway.

**document.getElementById()**

> The document.getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value and Returns null if no elements with the specified ID exists.An ID should be unique within a page.

**Jquery $()**

> Calling jQuery() or $() with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of either zero or one DOM element.Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers are old today as of 2019 you can directly access id keyed filds in javascript simply try it

```js
<p id="mytext"></p>
<script>mytext.innerText = 'Yes that works!'</script>
```

Online Demo!
- https://codepen.io/frank-dspeed/pen/mdywbre

Answer (score 2):

All the answers above are correct. In case you want to see it in action, don't forget you have Console in a browser where you can see the actual result crystal clear :

I have an HTML :

```
<div id="contents"></div>
```

Go to console `(cntrl+shift+c)` and use these commands to see your result clearly

```
document.getElementById('contents')
>>> div#contents

$('#contents')
>>> [div#contents,
 context: document,
 selector: "#contents",
 jquery: "1.10.1",
 constructor: function,
 init: function …]
```

As we can see, in the first case we got the tag itself (that is, strictly speaking, an HTMLDivElement object). In the latter we actually don’t have a plain object, but an array of objects. And as mentioned by other answers above, you can use the following command:

```
$('#contents')[0]
>>> div#contents
```