# jQuery $() vs. document.getElementByID -- differences

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [document.getElementById vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

More jQuery newbieisms to inflict on you folks...

I have some code that is using jQuery more or less happily. My confusion is that, in one case, I get my hands on an identifier which is the ID of a div on the page.  I expect that $(theIdentifier) will get its hands on the object, but it doesn't; console.log returns 'undefined'.  However, document.getElementById(theIdentifier) succeeds -- it returns the thing I'm looking for, and further operations on the div work as expected.

What's up here?  Shouldn't they be identical?  Why isn't the jQuery version working?

Puzzled, obviously; thanks for any advice!

Comment: Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: I think you need to read more about jQuery http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to "$()" has to be a **selector**:

```
var $thing = $("#" + thingId);
```

That's **almost** the same as calling "getElementById()". The difference is that the latter will **only** care about "id" values (except in IE, see below), while the jQuery selector-based code will pay attention to embedded CSS metacharacters.  Thus, if you've got an "id" value with a "." in it, like this:

```
var foo = $('#thing.special');
```

then that will look for an element with id "thing" and class "special", instead of an element with the id "thing.special".

The thing with IE: for reasons known only to some mysterious developers at Microsoft, the "getElementById()" code in IE will return elements whose "name" attribute matches the argument. That behavior is not dependent on the presence of an element with the same "id" value; I *think* it returns the first one it finds in the DOM. (I don't know about IE9 in this regard.)

**Note** — a comment mentions correctly that the "$()" function can take a variety of different types of arguments, resulting in a variety of effects.  When I said it "has to be a selector", I was referring to its use with string-valued arguments.

Comment: @pointy why the $ in the var name ?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Some use this convention for variables that contain jQuery objects.

Comment: @mcgrailm it's a convention, to make it easy to keep track of variables that hold jQuery objects from those that don't.  I'm of two minds about the practice, but it can be handy esp. in cases where you really want to minimize redundant jQuery calls.

Comment: no, the argument to `$()` can also be an HTMLElement object

Comment: @Alnitak yes of course you're right; I was writing in the context of the original question, but I'll clarify.  Thanks!

Comment: ARRRRRGGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!!!!  Of course.  I suck.  This is what I get for coding before my coffee kicks in.  Thanks much; sorry to have bothered you all.  You may now get back to more important/substantive things.

Answer (score 1):

you need $('#'+theIdentifier) to get by ID always have # at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

$ accepts a CSS selector, not an Identifier
so it's :

```
$('#' + identifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.getElementById('foo')
$(el)...
```

is equivalent to:

```
$('#foo')...
```

Comment: Not exactly.  getElementByID returns the actual DOM object.  $("#foo") returns a jquery object containing the DOM.  To get the actual DOM object (in case you need to manipulate it using non jquery methods like innerHTML=) you need to use $("#foo")[0].

Comment: @Demosophy you've misread what I wrote - I was saying that `$(document.getElementById('foo'))` is the same as `$('#foo')`.  Consider `el` as a temporary variable that's not otherwise used.