# Doesn't jQuery('#id') do the same thing as document.getElementById('#id') in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [document.getElementById vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

I have a function that will take all the spans with a certain class ("jobStatus") and remove an additional class from it ("orange"). I call the function from a SELECT onchange (onchange="chgJobstatus(this);"). It's working great.

However, I'm trying to get it to run on page load, based upon the selected value (this is server-side dynamically generated.)

This will work:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          chgJobstatus(document.getElementById("chgStatus"));
     });
```

This will NOT work:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
          chgJobstatus(jQuery('#chgStatus'));
     });
```

Doesn't jQuery('#id') do the same thing as document.getElementById('#id') ??

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery

Comment: I believe only $ is loaded unless you call noConflict().

Comment: you said that the elements are selected by a class "jobStatus", why are you selecting on ID at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding selecting the element, yes, but jQuery selectors return jQuery objects and `getElementById` returns a DOM Element object, you can get the DOM Element using `[index]` or `get(index)` method:

```
chgJobstatus(jQuery('#chgStatus')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `jQuery('#id')` returns a jquery object, with additional functions and properties attached to it.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but something like this could substitute all the javascript you've described.

```
$("#chgStatus")
  .bind("change", function() {
    $(".jobStatus").removeClass("orange");
  }).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work. `jQuery(selector)` always return a jQuery object `(jQuery(selector) instanceof jQuery is true )` . but you can get native dom element using .get or simply using array like syntax as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          chgJobstatus(jQuery('#chgStatus')[0]);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery('#id') - returns a jQuery Object
>
> document.getElementById('#id') - returns a HTML DOM Object
>
> jQuery('#id').get(0); ***OR*** jQuery('#id')[0]; - returns a HTML DOM Object

By using jquery it will allows you to access jquery functions. if you read below links you will get an good idea.

[document.getElementById vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

[jQuery $() vs. document.getElementByID — differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756928/jquery-vs-document-getelementbyid-differences)

[getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/27)

[jquery-sharp-vs-getelementbyid](http://jsperf.com/jquery-sharp-vs-getelementbyid/16)

[getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/21)

Answer (score 0):

On more important thing you should know is that jQuery returns a reference to a jQuery object, not the object itself.