# jQuery `hasClass()` doesn't produce any result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am simply trying to find out if the parent of the `A` (i.e. the `P`) has a class called `some_class` defined on it. I will then use the `true`/`false` result in a conditional.

I have a simple structure:

```
<div class="things">
    <p class="some_class">
        <a href="something">Link One</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

And some jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
    $('.things a').click(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();    
        alert($(e.target).parent()[0].nodeName); //works, displays "P"
        alert($(e.target).parent()[0].hasClass('some_class').toString()); //No output
        });
    });
```

The call to the second `alert()` does nothing - no alert box is displayed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

A [JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/LVerN/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert($(e.target).parent()[0].hasClass('some_class').toString())
```

in the line above you converted your Jquery Object back to a HTML DOM Object.  Therefore the hasClass method does not exist for `$(e.target).parent()[0]`.

Remove the `[0]`

```
alert($(e.target).parent().hasClass('some_class').toString())
```

Here is your fiddle that I modified http://jsfiddle.net/LVerN/5/

Comment: @Zabba... This is a link to an old question I answered and it should give you some insight on the difference between jQuery objects and HTML DOM Objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery/4070010#4070010

Comment: Thanks! Also using `$(this)` works. Time to read up on jQuery again!

Answer (score 1):

`hasClass()` is going to return a boolean value of `true` or `false`

```
$(e.target).parent()[0].hasClass()
```

Will return error because the object at index zero is not a jQuery object. So you'll want to remove the `[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVerN/6/)

```
<div class="things">
    <p class="some_class">
        <a href="something">Link One</a>
    </p>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('.things a').click(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();    
        //alert($(e.target).parent().nodeName); //Shows "undefined". wtf
        alert($(e.target).parent()[0].nodeName); //works
        alert($(this).parent().hasClass('some_class').toString()); //No output
    });
});
```