# How to get the onscreen pixel position of the text cursor?

Tags: javascript, cursor, textarea

How can I retrieve the pixel position (X and Y coordinates) of the textcursor within a `<textarea>` relative to the `<textarea>` or the viewport using JavaScript?

In my environment, dojo 1.6 is available.

I  have found solutions with jQuery achieving similar things, but unfortunately I don't have jQuery available.

Comment: I've just found http://stackoverflow.com/q/9012835/522479 but the accepted answer doesn't work in my browser (FF22) at least.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6953037/522479 is essentially the same thing. The accepted answer points towards third party solutions though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/128342/522479 is exactly what I need, but the accepted answer uses jQuery and some of it's material is lost because of external hosting.

Comment: https://github.com/Codecademy/textarea-helper/blob/master/textarea-helper.js looks very promising but sadly it's jQuery, too.

Answer (score 1):

The [`textarea-caret-position` component](https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position) is a dependency-free JS library that returns the top and left pixel coordinates of the text cursor (caret). Despite the name, it works for both `<textarea>`s and `<input>` elements.