# Get textarea caret pixel position

Tags: angular

I am trying to get the pixel location of the caret in a textarea I found some jquery examples but couldn´t find any examples using Angular2. 
Is there a way to handle this in Angular2?

Comment: query is just JS, as is angular 2, why not just use the query snippet your found? if you would like to keep jQ out of it (like i would prefer) just search for at vanilla js solution. Start by looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012835/find-caret-position-in-textarea-in-pixels