# document.getElementById() vs $()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [document.getElementById vs jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

I am learning jQuery and javascript.

- I wonder why the `$()` function of jQuery does not replace the `document.getElementById()` function of javascript.
- Isn't it the role of `$()` ?
- If not, what's the role of `$()` ?

I got to this question because `$().outerHeight` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Umm...jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: That's not the *only* role of `$()`...

Comment: `$()` can be used instead of `getElementById()` because it supports `#id` selectors.

Comment: here is the answer. no need to write it again : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery

Comment: Why would you want to **replace** `document.getElementById()`? Never replace native methods unless you really know what you do (sometimes you cannot even replace them). And strictly speaking, `getElementById` is not a JavaScript method in the sense of being part of JavaScript. It's method of the DOM API implemented in JavaScript (but that's probably nit pick ;)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` accepts selectors, HTML strings and regular JS objects. `getElementById` only accepts the `id` attribute of an element. They do different things.

You're trying to access a DOM object property, but from a jQuery object. jQuery objects wrap DOM objects, but they don't replace them.

To access the DOM object, you can use `$(...)[0]` (or `$(...).get(0)`) and your code should work just fine:

```
$(...)[0].outerHeight
```

Answer (score 1):

1) `$()` is the way you access any element in jQuery.

You can use any other keyword instead of `$` by:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

When you execute the above command, the element accessor becomes `jq()`.

2) `$()` does not really replaces `document.getElementById()`. But yes `$('#'+id)` replaces it. Since `$('.'+class)` also works, which is not a primitive property of DOM, I would just say it again `$()` is the way you access any element in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

First of $ is just used a select in jquery basically select(something) and something can be a class, id, html tag etc.

Hence the $ is not used just for selecting id

And this is the current syntax for using outerHeight
http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 0):

$() is invoking the `jQuery` function with a parameter. The parameter is a selector, which does not have to be an ID. Selectors select by DOM tree path, by class, by attribute, by ID, by tag name, etc. So the `jQuery` function is in no way equivalent to `document.getElementById()`.

Further more the jQuery function always returns a jQuery object, which the document.getElementById() returns a DOM element or `null`.

For outerHeight in jQuery you can use:

```
$('#Id').outerHeight(true); // Outer height with margins
$('#Id').outerHeight(); // Outer height without margins
```