# document.getElementById() alternative in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE: I'm sorry that my thread was misinterpreted by many users. I'll try to be more clear.
I'm using Drupal and I have created three floating banners. On the frontpage there is a block (block1) that displays one floating banner and after refresh the second one is appearing and for the third too.
Like a  wrote before these banners has a little X button to stop overflow.
I've putted this script in a one of the banners and it's working great.

```
<script language="javascript">
function doexpand() {
    document.getElementById("block1").style.overflow = "visible";
}

function dolittle() {
    document.getElementById("block1").style.overflow = "hidden";
}    
</script>
```

The real problem is that in categories pages I have #block2 and in articles #block3. 
These block are displaying the same banners. The code over is working only for a one ID. In this case #block1. document.getElementById is not working for more ID's as I read from other topics.

I've tried with jQuery with two blocks idents like this:

```
(function ($) {

    function doexpand() {
     $("#block1,#block2").css("overflow","visible");
    }
    function dolittle() {
     $("#block1,#block2").css("overflow","hidden");
    }

    })(jQuery);
```

It's not working.
The firebug/console displays: ReferenceError: doexpand is not defined.

I've tried with a single block too with jQuery like this:

```
(function ($) {

        function doexpand() {
         $("#block1").css("overflow","visible");
        }
        function dolittle() {
         $("#block1").css("overflow","hidden");
        }

        })(jQuery);
```

and it's displaying the same error.

Note: Drupal has a different wrapping and it's like this:

```
(function ($) {
        //your existing code
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should never have more than one HTML element with the same ID.

Comment: Please make a search before making a post. i hope its simple once we can able to find it in.

Comment: very first google search gives : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery

Comment: Why do everybody seem to think that OP gave the same ID to more than one element ?

Comment: @dystroy I'm wondering that too. I received many minuses for that, I guess.

Comment: +1, I don't see any reason for so many down votes, it's valid issue & seems misinterpreted by many.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look on [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

I think in your case, it is better to apply style with help of css for multiple elements. e.g. :

```
<script language="javascript">
function doexpand() {
    $('.block').style.overflow="visible";
}
function dolittle() {
    $('.block').style.overflow="hidden" ;
}
</script>
```

Please add `class="block"` to all of blocks for which you want to apply this style/function, it will apply on all of the blocks having css class "block".

Answer (score 1):

jQuery?

HTML:

```
<div class="block2"></div>
```

JS:

```
function doExpand(selector) {
    if ( $(selector).length ) {
        $(selector).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    }
}
```

Calling with non ID selector would look like this: (jQuery syntax): 
doExpand('.block2');

Answer (score 0):

The above code is perfectly valid in jQuery (which is a JavaScript library).

If you want to use a more typical jQuery code, you can do

```
$('#block1').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

You can expend it to multiple id like this :

```
$('#block1, #block2').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

You always can get the DOM object from a jQuery object, which means you could also have adapted your code to use jQuery selectors using

```
$('#block1').get(0).style.overflow="visible";
```

(this specific example isn't smart : no need to use jQuery if you don't use a complex selector or jQuery functions)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple really, jQuery selection is based on css selectors for the most part. These selectors are then translated into an array of dom objects held in a jQuery object.

```
function doexpand() {
 $("#block1").css("overflow","visible");
}
function dolittle() {
 $("#block1").css("overflow","hidden");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never have more than one HTML element with the same ID (Which is why `document.getElementById` only returns one element)

You can just refeerence `block2`, `block3` directly `document.getElementById("block2").style.overflow="hidden" ;`

Or use `getElementByClassName`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass")
```

Which will pick up all elements with a specific class.

If you want to use `jQuery` like the other answers are suggesting you can match on the element name.  For example:

```
$('div[id^="block"]').css("overflow", "visible");
```

This will match all `div` element where their `ID` starts with `block`.  You can also use other wildcards such as `*` for contains and `$` for ends with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Javascript Code in jQuery. I dont understand what you want do do, but you could pass the params in the function. Example under this code.

```
<script language="javascript">
function doexpand() {
$("#block1").css({'overflow': 'visible'});
}
function dolittle() {
$("#block1").css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
}
</script>
```

Here is it

```
<script language="javascript">
function doexpand(element) {
$("#" + element).css({'overflow': 'visible'});
}
function dolittle(element) {
$("#" + element).css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
}
</script>
```

Than you could call it like: `doexpand("theIDofTheElement");`

Answer (score -1):

Alternative to `document.getElementById("an_element);`
in Jquery is: $("#an_element");
It will work fine in JQuery, it's just that JQuery makes things faster and less verbose.