# Get the div id and the class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a snippet of code that is able to retrieve the div, but I am also after the class

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            document.onmouseover = function(e) {
                var divID = e.target.id;
            }
        });
```

This works great, but I also need to get the div class, I was hoping to do something like `var divClass = e.target.class` but no dice.

Comment: You might want to have a look at
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
e.target.className
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `document.getElementById`? You already have a reference to the element with `e.target`. `e.target.className` should be plenty fine