# Converting between a jQuery object and a pure js object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between the object returned by `$('#elementID')` and the object returned by `document.getElementById('elementID')`?

Moreover, how can you easily convert from one to the other? For instance:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    // How can I access 'this' as a pure javascript object instead of as a jQuery object?
});
```

This has plagued me for some time now. I know you shouldn't mix the two, really, but I just want to understand the principle.

Comment: Just pass it into the `$` constructor: `$(document.getElementById('id'))`. To get the DOM object back out, use `.get()` or `[0]`.

Comment: You should make that an answer with clear examples :)

Comment: @Aerovistae homework? :)

Comment: LOL actually no. Does it smack of academic origins? No, this is to resolve my slowness in knowing how to combine jQuery with regular JS when writing practical code.

Comment: Under the hood, a jQuery object is an array of DOM elements, such as those you'd get using `getElementById()` (in combination with other `getElementByWhatever()` methods and whatever else Sizzle, the selector engine does), that has a bunch of methods attached to it.

Comment: Regarding your `$.each` question: `this` in that case will be a regular DOM node, not a jquery object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.getElementById vs jQuery $()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

Comment: Can I just chime in and emphasize what @bfavaretto said? There is no need for conversion inside the `each` block. Just use either `this` to access the DOM object or `$(this)` to access the jQuery object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> What is the difference between the object returned by `$('#elementID')` and the object returned by `document.getElementById('elementID')`?

`$('#elementID')` returns an object with a ton of functions that all operate on the result of `document.getElementById('elementID')`. Think of the jQuery object like a giant robot that `document.getElementById('elementID')` is sitting inside of.

You can access the wrapped DOM object with:

- `$('#elementID').get()`
- `$('#elementID').get(0)`
- `$('#elementID')[0]`

If there's more than one element matched by the selector, you can access, for example, the second element with `$elements.get(1)` or `$elements[1]`.

> Moreover, how can you easily convert from one to the other?

To wrap an object with jQuery's convenience functions, just pass it into the `$` function:

```
$(document.getElementById('foo'))
$(document.querySelectorAll('.foo:not(.bar)'))
```

To go the other way, use `.get()` or the bracket notation.

In your specific example, you don't need to do anything special because `this` is actually a normal DOM object. This is why you often see callbacks littered with `$(this)`.

Comment: I don't think there's a need for the first 2 paragraphs of this answer. To me the OP clearly shows that he understands that a jQuery object is a wrapper around DOM nodes. He just wants to understand how and how to convert between them. A simple, straightforward answer would be better not only for the OP but also for future "duplicate questions" which may be redirected to this answer. Apart from that, good answer and a very complete explanation.

Comment: @slebetman The OP (to me, very clearly) asks two questions in the body of his post. This answer actually quotes (and subsequently answers) both. I don't think your objection holds water.

Comment: @millimoose: The first two paragraphs have been deleted. The original first two paragraphs explains that jQuery is not magic and is written in javascript and is a wrapper around DOM objects. I think the OP understands that. The current first 2 paragraphs is OK by me.

Answer (score 6):

A jquery object is just an array with special functions

```
// non-jquery -> jquery
var a = document.getElementById('some-link'); // one element
var $a = $(a);

// jquery -> non-jquery
a = $a[0]; // a jquery element holds all of its matches in the indices 0..(a.length) just like a  JS array
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery objects contain both properties that describe the object and methods(functions) to interact with that object

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code for creating a simple javascript element array but some cases i found i need to use the same element as jQuery object. then i found following solution to do it.

```
var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('deletecheck');
var len = cboxes.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if (cboxes[i].checked){
            jQuery(cboxes[i]).parent().parent().remove();
    }
}
```