# Detecting HTML5 input's form attribute and try serialize if not support

Tags: jquery, html, modernizr

I have some input fields outside the form. using HTML5 form attribute

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
<input form="myform" type="hidden" name="extra" id="extra" value="777" />
<select form="myform" name="filter" id="filter">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

and try serialize form on submit

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    var query = $(this).serialize();
    if ($.browser.msie) { 
        //fixed form attribute not supported in IE
        var extra = $('[form=myform]').each(function () {
            if (/(=)\w*/gi.test(query)) query += '&';
            query += this.name + '=' + this.value;
        });
    }
    console.log(query);
    return false;
});
```

but currently http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/ said

> "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature
>   detection instead."

so how do I detect that browser suppport this form attribute feature? 
or is there a better approach to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to check for the `form` attribute without using an external plugin or library you could try the following:

**Change:**

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
```

**To:**

```
if ($("#extra")[0].form === null) {
```

See [document.getElementById vs jQuery $()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery) for more information on why `$("#extra")[0]` is used.

**Resulting in:**

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    var query = $(this).serialize();
    if ($("#extra")[0].form === null) { 
        //fixed form attribute not supported in IE
        var extra = $('[form=myform]').each(function () {
            if (/(=)\w*/gi.test(query)) query += '&';
            query += this.name + '=' + this.value;
        });
    }
    console.log(query);
    return false;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ezq9mu1a/1/

As far as I am aware this is the sort of check that Modernizr does (although I think it dynamically creates the input to test on). Running this fiddle in IE triggers the fallback code while Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera just use `serialize`.

**EDIT**

As we can't rely on an existing element in the page we will need to create a test `form` and `input` for the purposes of checking if the `form` attribute is supported. To do this we can modify the code in the following way:

**Add:**

```
//Create test elements and amend them to the DOM
var testForm = $('<form />', { 'id': "testForm" })[0];
var testInput = $('<input />', { 'form': "testForm" })[0];
$('body').append(testForm, testInput);
//Set a variable to store whether the form attribute is supported
var formSupported = (testInput.form !== null) ? true : false;
//Remove the test elements from the DOM
$(testForm).remove();
$(testInput).remove();
```

**Change:**

```
if ($("#extra")[0].form === null) {
```

**To:**

```
if (!formSupported) {
```

**Resulting in:**

```
//Create test elements and amend them to the DOM
var testForm = $('<form />', { 'id': "testForm" })[0];
var testInput = $('<input />', { 'form': "testForm" })[0];
$('body').append(testForm, testInput);
//Set a variable to store whether the form attribute is supported
var formSupported = (testInput.form !== null) ? true : false;
//Remove the test elements from the DOM
$(testForm).remove();
$(testInput).remove();

if (!formSupported) {
    $("#formSupported").html("No");
}

$('#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
    var query = $(this).serialize();
    if (!formSupported) { 
        //fixed form attribute not supported in IE
        var extra = $('[form=myform]').each(function () {
            if (/(=)\w*/gi.test(query)) query += '&';
            query += this.name + '=' + this.value;
        });
    }
    console.log(query);
    return false;
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/ezq9mu1a/3/

Comment: Thanks, may be the simplest way to check if attribute is supported  but the reason I placing `<input>` outside `<form>` is I'm implementing plugin architecture that load extra fields on run time so that I can't use actual input's ID

Comment: No problem, please see my edit which uses dynamically created elements to do the same check. This may be more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery Migrate plugin https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Or use modernizr (http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Edit, updated

Note, Tried at ie 11

v2

```
// click `test`
$("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if ("msFlex" in document.body.style) {
var query = "";
$("[form=myform]").not("form *").each(function (k, v) {
    var params = ["name", "value"];
    $.each(params, function (i, val) {
        query += (val === "name" 
                   ? "&" + $(v).prop(val) + "=" 
                   : $(v).prop(val)
                   );
    });
});
// do stuff
// tried at ie11 , `$("[form=myform]").serialize()`
// appear to serialize those elements ?
// see `console` ?
// either `query` or `$("[form=myform]").serialize()`
// should return `&extra=777&filter=1` 
// possible reason `checkFormAttr()` returned `true` ?
// tried `v1` with `checkFormAttr()` ? without `!` ?
console.log(query, $("[form=myform]").serialize());
$("body").append(query)
};
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/g4v2fcaa/10/ (v2)

`&extra=777&filter=1`

should be append to document

v1

```
function checkFormAttr() {
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.id = "abc";
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.form = "abc";
  form.appendChild(input);
  console.log(form, input.form);
  // (form === input.form) => `true` if supported 
  // (form !== input.form) => cast as `false`
  return (form === input.form) // `false` if not supported
};
```

for including within piece at OP ,

```
$("#myform").on("submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var query = $(this).serialize();
    if (!checkFormAttr()) { 
        //fixed form attribute not supported in IE
        var extra = $('[form=myform]').each(function () {
            if (/(=)\w*/gi.test(query)) query += '&';
            query += this.name + '=' + this.value;
        });
    }
    console.log(query);
    return false;
});
```

alternatively , to check `document.body.style` for specific `vendor-prefixes` ,

```
var ms = (("msFlex" || "msAnimation") in document.body.style );
var webkit = ("WebkitAnimation" in document.body.style );
var moz = ("MozAnimation" in document.body.style );
var opera = ("OTransition" in document.body.style );

console.log("form attribute:"+ checkFormAttr()
            + "\nform attribute , cast as `false`:"+ !checkFormAttr()
            + "\nms:" + ms 
            + "\nwebkit:" + webkit
            + "\nmoz:" + moz 
            + "\nopera:" + opera);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/g4v2fcaa/

See  [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) at [4.10.18.3 Association of controls and forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form)

Comment: doesn't seems to works on IE 11.. checking form attr return true but not being serialized :(

Comment: What does `console.log(query);` return ?

Comment: @PasitR. Try `if (checkFormAttr() === false)`