# InnerHTML - Self invoking function works, but why doesn't Jquery document ready work?

Tags: innerhtml, document-ready, self-invoking-function

I was testing to write something in innerHTML, without any event handler. I'm wondering why **Jquery document ready** didn't work - I thought it was supposed to be a self invoking function? The regular self invoking function did work.

If I have this in HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <p><span id="html_span1"></span></p>
  <p><span id="html_span2"></span></p>
</div>
```

In JS, the regular self invoking function works:

```
(function(){
     document.getElementById('html_span1').innerHTML = "self invoking function works";
}());
```

But not Jquery ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('html_span2').innerHTML = "Is this displayed?";
});
```

If I place the Jquery function at the top, then the other function stops working - how come?
Also, the self evoking function, which ends with }());  - the extra parenthesis is very important, otherwise it's not working. I don't understand the meaning of that parenthesis though?

Comment: $(document).ready is not a self-invoking function. That means self-invoking will invoke itself as soon as JS interprets that code. $(document).ready will be called when page is loaded

Comment: Okay, that cleared things up, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery better use selectors:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#html_span2").html("Is this displayed?");
});
```

See it running and play with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/c66t0tb2/

Comment: Thanks, so it's not good to use regular javascript (like getElementById) in a Jquery function? Seems that I have missed some general rule..

Comment: No, but JQuery has a lot of powerful that you are missing. Is a JS framework to resolve a lot of problems and things. Selectors are one of the better things that JQuery has. If you already load it, why don't use it?

Comment: Actually JQuery is regular javascript. Is not a language.

Comment: Yeah, true, but then there has to be some explanation for why document.getElementById().innerHTML didn't work inside a Jquery ready function. But I'm gonna follow your advice anyhow!

Comment: But are not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery

Comment: I did a silly mistake - something else probably caused the error originally, but when I did testings in the online editor (Codepen), I didn't realize that Jquery was (probably) not enabled there.Thanks for showing that it works.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was good for you, please upvoted it. If it answers your question, please mark it as accepted. You will gain points in this way and everyone will know that you mark your answer. So the next time people will answer you more often and better.

Comment: Sure, but I'll have to wait until I get 15 reputation points, I will upvote once I get there.

Comment: oh! mmmm if you ask something more comment here :)