# Function only works with getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function to attach a event:

```
function addEvent(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (object.attachEvent) {
        object.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    } else {
        object["on"+type] = callback;
    }
};
```

And a tiny button to test:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle" id="btn-toggle-action">Toggle</a>
```

I try to call it but I've seen:

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('btn-toggle-action'), 'click', function(e) {}); //WORKS

addEvent(document.getElementByClassName('btn-toggle'), 'click', function(e) {}); //DON'T WORK

addEvent($('.btn-toggle'), 'click', function(e) {}): //DON'T WORK

addEvent($('#btn-toggle-action'), 'click', function(e) {}); //DON'T WORK
```

I'd like to understand why it can't work with all methods.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this function.... if you want to bind events to elements then why not just use `document.getElementById('element').addEventListener('click', function(){});` or jQuery's `$('#element').on('click', function(){});` it's like you're trying to reinvent the wheel..

Comment: `$(anything)` returns a jQuery object, not an element ... `document.getElementByClassName` is not even an existing function ... the only version above that returns an element is `document.getElementById` - your developer tools console would've alerted you to these fundamental errors

Comment: NewToJS, the client want his site works on IE8 then I need to use attachEvent too. And yes I could use $('...') but as we use this function to handle some window events (resize, ...) i'd like to use this function to have a "better" code instead of $('..'), addEvent mixed.  And the last but not the least I've learnt a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, write error: `document.getElementByClassName` should  be `document.getElementsByClassName`, because it select mutiple elements.

jquery selector is diffrent from native selector, see [document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)

You can use more powerful native selector  like:

`document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-action')`

`document.querySelectorAll('.btn-toggle')`

Comment: or `document.querySelector('.btn-toggle')` to get a single (first) element with such a class, is perfectly valid too

Answer (score -1):

May be document.getElementByClassName('btn-toggle') returns array of objects. Need:

```js
if(typeof object === 'array'){
  for(obj in object){
    ...
  }
}
```

PS. The $() returns $-object, but no dom-element.

Comment: `May be document.getElementByClassName('btn-toggle') returns array of objects` - may be it doesn't because there's no such function