# Issue communication with postMessage from parent to child iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I'm having an issue communicating from my parent window to the child iFrame. But in the other side, everything works perfectly. 
Here is how I get the chil iFrame object in order to fire the ***postMessage*** function:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('Frame').contentWindow;
```

When I print it int he console, I get the following:

```
Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 0, frames: Window…}
```

When I proceed to the postMessage function as follows:

```
iFrame.postMessage("message", "http://contoso.com");
```

It shows me an error when loading the page: ***iFrame.postMessage is not a function***.
When I execute the postMessage in console, I get an ***undefined***

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You still need to have control of both websites. Do you own `contoso.com`?

Comment: You need to setup e.origin on `contoso.com`,  are you sure you are able to edit that site? Last time I checked, MS still owned it.

Comment: I've replaced my website by contoso.com just for the post. In the event listener in the child iFrame, the e.origin is set correctly. I've added log just before manipulating the event object but it never gets to that point.

Comment: Maybe this answer might help.

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById('Frame');
iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage("message", "http://contoso.com");
```

I had this problem too. I found solution from this website https://www.viget.com/articles/using-javascript-postmessage-to-talk-to-iframes

Comment: Error: `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided  does not match the recipient window's origin.`  It works from child element to parent but not the way around.

Comment: @temo I was able to get it working cross domain, see my answer below.

Comment: the below solution from @Djave works, we need to store the source in the parents addEventListener (in some variable or in an array if your use case involves multiple child iframe communication) when the child iframe does a postMessage to the parent for the first time. This source can then be used to communicate from parent to child.

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't able to get this working using a `querySelector` approach.

What worked for me was the following. I'll refer to the two webpages as the `parent` that has an iframe on it and the `src` as the page inside the iframe.

On the `src` page, I post a message, with the `parent` url as the origin:

```
// src
window.parent.postMessage({
  type: "connect",
  url: window.location.href
}, "http://iframeparent.dev", );
```

Then in the `parent` page, I listen for this. It will have a property called `source` which is the iframe in question. This property **can be posted to**.

```
// parent
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  // this is the magic connection:
  event.source; 
}, false);
```

So you could do something like:

```
// parent
let sources = [];

window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  sources.push(event.source);
}, false);

function something() {
  sources.forEach(source => {
    source.postMessage({some: "data"}, "http://iframesrc.dev")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code also works.

`$('#id')[0].contentWindow.postMessage("hello world",targetOrigin);`

There is a difference between jQuery selector and document.getElementById.

Document.getElementByID returns HTML DOM object.
jQuery selector returns jQuery object.

For more information please find below link.
[document.getElementById vs jQuery $()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069982/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery)