# Using jQuery to select by id versus array index

Tags: javascript, jquery

When jQuery returns an array of DOM elements, I am struggling to understand how that differs from when jQuery returns a single DOM element, as in the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A simple login form</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateInput() {
    var input = $('input');
    var passwordById = $("#password1");
    var passwordByIndex = input[0];
    // What's the difference between these?
    passwordById.val(); // Value of password field
    passwordByIndex.val(); // Undefined!
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <h2>Username</h2>
    <input type="text" id="username" required>
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input type="password" id="password" required>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="validateInput()">
</form>
</body>
```

I want to use passwordByIndex because I wish to iterate over array $('input').

Comment: passwordByIndex is one single character, extracted from `input`, it doesn't have any properties, like `.val()`.

Comment: if you're wanting to do an index-based lookup of an element, don't hook the array. Instead, use .eq() or :eq(). Example: `$('input:eq(0)')` or `$('input').eq(0)`

Comment: input[0] gets the first dom element. If you wanted it as a Jquery object you could do $(input[0]) and get the val() from that. Then that and passwordById are identical. The best choice depends entirely on your circumstances. :)

Comment: Dom and Jquery objects are very different things. :)

Comment: try like this:
var passwordByIndex = $(input[0]);

Comment: BTW `passwordByIndex = input[1]` not `[0]`. Once you know that and convert it to a jQuery object you'll get back the exact same thing as `passwordByID.val()`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is that one is a jQuery object and one is a DOM element. Take the following code snippet to help:

```
// this gives me a jQuery object. Might reference one element, might reference multiple
var jQueryElement = $(".myclass");

// I can just call jQuery routines on the jQuery element:
var innerHtml = jQueryElement.html();

// this would give me a dom element
var domElement = jQueryElement[0];

// ... to call jQuery routines on a traditional element I need get back
//     to a jQuery object:
var myHTML = $(domElement).html();
```

Hopefully this helps explain the difference. As noted in the comments above, you might find the following questions useful:

- More about the difference - [jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)
- Convert DOM to jQuery object - [How can I convert a DOM element to a jQuery element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625936/how-can-i-convert-a-dom-element-to-a-jquery-element)
- Convert jQuery object to DOM element - http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, getting the DOM element (in my case by the index) is a bad idea, because that's browser-specific (whereas jQuery objects aren't).

Comment: @petehern DOM elements aren't really browser specific, just certain properties on them are. There are a number of properties that you can use that work across pretty much all major browsers. Look up the property you want to get or set on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and you can probably find a way to do it across most major browsers. jQuery just simplifies this checking process and provides a nice framework for handling the really strange cases. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`input[0]` returns a DOM element that isn't a jQuery object. `$('#password1')` gets the `password1` DOM element using its ID tag, and turns it into a jQuery object. A jQuery object is a special array-like object, with methods added that allow you to do things like `$('#password1').val()`. (Read more about the jQuery object [HERE](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/))

If you do `$('input')[0]`, like you have done, or even `$('#password1')[0]`, it gets the plain (non-jQuery) DOM element at index 0 of the special jQuery array-like object. Therefore, you do not have access to the special jQuery methods like `.val()`.

You can do `$(input[0])` if you want to turn it back into a jQuery object to be able to use `.val()`. In which case, you'd do `$(input[0]).val()`.