# set Text in specific element using getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a class named `p1` that I gave to several paragraphs.

Now I want to get the **first one** and change its text.

I tried something like this:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
p[0].text("hello");
```

or

```
p[0].innerHtml = "hello";
```

Comment: Text will work only when `p[0]` is `option` or `script` element (are there others having `text` property?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you have three options to do what you want:

- You can simply use jQuery's `eq` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)):

  `$(".p1").eq(0).text("hello");`
- Or, you can use DOM API like you did in the example (**but if you're using jQuery already, I'd recommend to keep consistency and stick with it**) and then **[convert DOM element to jQuery element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625936/how-can-i-convert-a-dom-element-to-a-jquery-element)**:

  `var p = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
  $(p[0]).text("hello");`
- Or just use plain DOM API, but use **innerText** (by the way, remember to always use innerText if inserting any text to element to avoid problems like code injection (you can read more [here](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/12/38/)) instead:

  `var p = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
  p[0].innerText = "hello";`

**See all examples in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thLejpsd/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Not `p[0].innerHtml = "hello";` change it to `p[0].innerHTML = "hello";`

```js
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("p1");
p[0].innerHTML = "hello";
```

```html
<div class="p1"></div>
```

REF : **[Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)**

As you were tagged jQuery in your question ,you can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** or **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

```js
$('.p1').html('hello');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="p1"></div>
```